# Apache Nifi docker-compose with Traefik reverse proxy does not work with multiple networks

Tags: docker, docker-compose, apache-nifi, traefik

I currently have an Apache NiFi setup that I access via server:port. I now want to route the UI over my traefik reverse proxy, but doing this via docker network and tags does not work as expected:

When adding the reverse proxy network `reverse-proxy_internal_network` to the nifi container, it is no longer accessible via the port (even though the binding is still the same). I suspect some sort of binding issue within the container.
In addition, sometimes accessing the url https://apache-nifi.server.com/nifi throws a "Bad Gateway" response, as traefik is unable to find the jetty server on the IP on its network, as it is probably bound to the `apache-nifi-etl_network`. This behaviour seems to be random, depending on which network "wins".

```
version: "3.9"

services:
  nifi:
    image: apache/nifi:1.23.2
    hostname: nifi-etl
    networks:
      apache-nifi-etl_network:
      reverse-proxy_internal_network:
    ports: 
      - 7443:7443
    environment:
      - NIFI_WEB_HTTP_PORT=7443
    volumes:
      - nifi_database_repository:/opt/nifi/nifi-current/database_repository
      - nifi_flowfile_repository:/opt/nifi/nifi-current/flowfile_repository
      - nifi_content_repository:/opt/nifi/nifi-current/content_repository
      - nifi_provenance_repository:/opt/nifi/nifi-current/provenance_repository
      - nifi_state:/opt/nifi/nifi-current/state
      - nifi_logs:/opt/nifi/nifi-current/logs
      - nifi_conf:/opt/nifi/nifi-current/conf
      - nifi_additional_drivers:/opt/nifi/nifi-current/drivers
    labels:

      - traefik.enable=true
      - traefik.http.services.nifi.loadbalancer.server.port=7443
      - traefik.http.routers.nifi.entrypoints=web,websecure
      - traefik.http.routers.nifi.middlewares=internal-only@file,https-redirect@file
      - traefik.http.routers.nifi.rule=Host(`apache-nifi.server.com`) && PathPrefix(`/nifi`)

    restart: always
networks:
  apache-nifi-etl_network:
  reverse-proxy_internal_network:
    external: true

volumes:
  nifi_database_repository:
  nifi_flowfile_repository:
  nifi_content_repository:
  nifi_provenance_repository:
  nifi_state:
  nifi_logs:
  nifi_conf:
  nifi_additional_drivers:
```

Removing the `apache-nifi-etl_network` and only having the reverse proxy network solves the issue with the routing problems, making the service available via the hostname, but this is sadly no solution, as this network is limited in its range.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just figured it out (after countless hours). The issue was resolved by adding `- NIFI_WEB_HTTP_HOST=0.0.0.0` to the environment section of the docker compose.
This way the internal web server is bound to all available network interfaces, not just the one that "wins" (as stated in my question)